# Failable Initializer for Decodable Classes

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

I would like the initialization to return nil in case title is missing.

1. Adding a `?` to `init` produces the following error:

> Non-failable initializer requirement 'init(from:)' cannot be satisfied by a failable initializer ('init?')

2. Adding a `if title == nil { return nil}` produces the following error:

> Only a failable initializer can return 'nil'

```
class ClassA: Decodable {

    let title: String
    let subtitle: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case subtitle
    }

   required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

// changing the signature to:
// required init?(from decoder: Decoder) throws
// produced: 
// Non-failable initializer requirement 'init(from:)' cannot be satisfied by a failable initializer ('init?')

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        guard let theTitle = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title) else {

            return nil // Only a failable initializer can return 'nil'


        }

        title = theTitle
        subtitle = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .subtitle)
   }
}
```

Comment: Is `throwing` some error with meaningful description an option? I mean this `init` is throwable, and it's more versatile than `failable`

Comment: You can just throw some error like `throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(String.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Title not found"))`

Comment: Please don't repost questions. And don't use a failable initializer for missing keys with `Codable` at all. All encoding/ decdoding methods `throw`. Conform to that pattern by making the struct member / class property `optional` or implement `init(from:` and `decodeIfPresent`

Comment: @Kamran I am decoding an array of ClassA objects. Throwing an error when title is missing in one of them, makes the whole array nil. I would like only one item in the array to be nil. The one without the title.

Comment: @user28434, I am decoding an array of ClassA objects. Throwing an error when the title is missing in one of them, makes the whole array nil. I would like only one item in the array to be nil. The one without the title.

Answer (score 1):

**`Failable initializer`** is not available for `Codable` types for now.

Also, I don't think a `failable initializer` is even required for this case. You will automatically get `nil` for object if `title` is not available in the *JSON* since it is not an `optional`.

And, there is no requirement of `enum CodingKeys` because the *property names*  match the *JSON keys* as per your code.

Neither `init(from:)` implementation is required because you're not doing any specific parsing here.

Keep the model as clean as possible like,

```
class ClassA: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String?
}
```

You can parse your *JSON response* using,

```
let classA = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ClassA.self, from: data)
```

Comment: It is a simplified code of a complex class, with properties that do not match coding keys and custom decoder